# First full backup on USB: Permission denied

Tags: usb, permissions, backup

I am new to Ubuntu 13.04.  I am trying to do a full backup to my USB and I have used GParted to create a partition on my USB and formatted it as ext4.  It still has permission denied errors. I get this message:

```
Permission denied when trying to create ‘/media/stacyjane/ubuntu backup/duplicity-full.20130726T043854Z.vol1.difftar.gpg
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/324705/edit) your question and add commands you used.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set ownership & permissions.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

If mounted at /media/stacyjane

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwX,o-w /media/stacyjane
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/stacyjane
```

Note that the -R is recursion and everything is changed, do NOT run on any system partitions.
All directories will be 775.
All files will be 664 except those that were set as executable to begin with.

The -R parameter is recursive, so it will apply to all lower directories & files, but do not use on any system partition, just data.

see also

```
man chmod
man chown
```

Comment: hi oldfred..thank you so much for the commands.  I copied your commands, and it did change the permissions on the usb to create and delete, but when I tried to run the first full backup, now I am getting: Backup location ‘/tmp/duplicity-wc_Bzd-tempdir/mktemp-_0VJzA-2’ does not exist.