# suddenly don't have acces to Mounted Drives, chown/chmod don't help

Tags: permissions, external-hdd, chown

I'm having some trouble with a few drives in my computer. I have been unable to access 3 drives (one internal and two external) except as root for the past day.

All three drives are ext4 and I was able to access them before. This problem persists between my laptop (Ubuntu 15.04) and a Raspberry Pi 2 I have set up as a NAS (what the external drives are for).

I have been unable to fix this error running commands such as this

```
sudo chmod 666 mnt/nameofadrive/ (this was run on the pi)

sudo chown username '/media/username/Storage'
```

(this was run on my laptop, the name of the drive is Storage).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can do to rectify this situation?
Thank you.

Comment: If you used `sudo chmod 666` will give you read and write privileges, but you need execute permission to look inside any directories. You may want to try 777 instead, though this isn't very secure, it can definitely let you know if permissions are the problem.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. Thank you. I feel dumb now.

Comment: No need! I only found that out a little while back, common sense was telling me that if a directory is readable, you should be able to see the contents. Is it all working properly now?

Comment: Do you mind if I change my comment to an answer, so you can accept it and we can close the question?

Comment: Some alternative commands: http://askubuntu.com/questions/324705/first-full-backup-on-usb-permission-denied/324942#324942 Generally better to not use numberical hex settings.

Comment: Why not @oldfred ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used:

```
sudo chmod 666 /mnt/nameofdrive
```

It will give you read and write privileges, but you need execute permission to look inside any directories. You may want to try 777 instead, though this is entirely insecure, it can definitely let you know if permissions are causing the problems.