# Partitioning SSDs

Tags: partitioning, ssd, home-directory

I'm a lifelong Windows user, and absolutely new to Ubuntu. I just built this new computer and wanted Ubuntu on it, but there's a bit of a learning curve...

I have a 32GB SSD (sdb) that I would like to be just for booting and other important system things,

and a 256GB SSD (sda) that I would like to throw documents, games, and other files and media into.

Currently, everything is on the 32GB, and every time that I make a partition on the 250GB, I am unable to move any files over because it says I do not have permission, which is emotionally hurtful because I just made it and have administrator status.

I downloaded a couple of games, and they play and run well, but everything is on the 32GB, which is running out of room, as I probably should have seen coming.

So how do I get the games and downloads and such fluff (home directory?) to the bigger SSD, and have new downloads and docs default to there as well?

I appreciate all help in advance.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage And you may need to chmod & chown your partitions if Linux formatted. One example here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/324705/first-full-backup-on-usb-permission-denied/324942#324942

Comment: Thank you everyone for advice. I tried Takkat's suggestion first and it seems to have successfully solved the issue. I had been to that thread before but I don't know why I didn't follow through with it. I apologize; more research on my part could have saved us all time.

Follow-up noob question, how can I mark this as solved if Takkat's help is only a comment, not an answer?

Comment: I marked your question as a duplicate to the other question I linked to above. By "closing" your question here other people will be directed to the right place. You can agree to that if you like then your question will immediately be linked that duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just want Ubuntu and NOT Windows at all.
In this case when the Installation is happening - go ahead with the default options - it will create single root '/' partition and another one 'swap' and then you are good to go.
You might want to change your partition size later and for that you can install gparted

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

And if needed make use of LVM. For your current needs I will just say keep things simple.

Comment: Right, I guess that didn't make that clear. I ONLY wanted Ubuntu. I had already installed Ubuntu and used the default options. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Way back at the start of my Linux journey, I used this guide:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-partplan/
It still forms a good basis for what you want to do but do bear in mind that it's 16 years old.  Details like the type of partition you're using will be different, e.g. ext4 not ext2.  Using a GUI tool like Gparted rather than some of the command line options may well work better too.

Comment: Thank you. I took a look at this, and I was using Gparted - visual interface is a lot easier to begin with than the command line.