# How to change ownership of the partitions

Tags: 14.04, ownership

I am new to Linux. After installing Ubuntu 14.04 I created two new partitions . But when i tried to save something onto those directories nothing happens. In their property ,it is shown that the owner is root . Please help me so that i can use those two directories. I tried using sudo chown -R username:group directory.But it is saying invalid username.

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /{directoryofpartition}/`

Comment: I like chmod also for permissions similar to /home's permissions: `sudo chmod -R a+rwX,o-w /{directoryofpartition}/`  I use this as my data partition is mounted at /mnt/data: `sudo chmod -R a+rwX,o-w /mnt/data` Another example with both chmod & chown: http://askubuntu.com/questions/324705/first-full-backup-on-usb-permission-denied/324942#324942

Answer (score 1):

I came here because I had the same problem, and I'm also a novice, and I use Ubuntu because it is open source, not because I'm interested in learning Linux. The command Rinzwind suggested didn't work for me, and after looking up more about chmod I was nervous about using the suggestion in the comment by oldfred, being a beginner.

These instructions worked, and seemed a lot less likely to bork my system if I made a mistake:

[How To Set Write Permissions on Ext4 Partitions in Ubuntu Linux](https://itsfoss.com/set-write-permission-ext4-partition-ubuntu-linux/)