# I want to give an external hardrive executable permissions, how do I do it?

Tags: hard-drive, games, steam, external-hdd

My computer only has 31 Gigabytes and I cant install games. Ive tryied downloadig games from steam and form Itch.io on my hardrive but it wont let me because the hardrive doesn't have execute permissions. How do I fix this?

Comment: What format is partition on external drive? If Windows NTFS permissions are set by mount. If Linux you have individual control over execute which offers more protection from virus programs. IF ext4: https://askubuntu.com/questions/324705/first-full-backup-on-usb-permission-denied/324942#324942 Then you can add +x on individual files.

Comment: I would also recommend a linux file system for example `ext4`. But if you want a Microsoft file system (NTFS, FAT32 or exFAT), you can set execute permissions according to this link, [Mount NTFS partition in a USB drive with custom permissions and owner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072)