# How to mount external hdd with ext4 partitions?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have HHD disk from my old laptop with 2 ext4 and swap partitions. I put it into the case and plug in it. But I wasn't able to find it in /dev but after rebooting of my Kubuntu I found /dev/sdc (I have 2 ssd disks in system). But when I tried to execute

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdc /media/oldhdd/
```

I get the error:

> mount: /media/oldhdd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on
>   /dev/sdc, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

I think it happens due to hdd has a few partitions. Please help me to mount my hdd.

Comment: Try to find correct device with `lsblk -f`.

Comment: You do not mount drives like sda, but partitions like sda1 or sda2 or sdc1 etc. How to manually mount: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition if you need ownership & permissions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/324705/first-full-backup-on-usb-permission-denied/324942#324942