# chown won't let me change owner of drive and keeps saying invalid user when I'm the ONLY user

Tags: chown

`chown` just won't work. I added a second hard drive to Ubuntu, formatted to ext4 with label hpmachine for file storage. Rebooted, and it mounts fine. I changed the permissions with `chmod -R 777`, but I can't get chown to let me change the owner of the drive. When I type `sudo chown -R first /hpmachine`, I keep getting this error: `chown: invalid user: 'first'`.

I'm trying to use "first" which is the name I put in on the login screen when I installed Ubuntu. "first" is the ONLY user on this Ubuntu computer. I need this second hard drive to let other computers on the LAN to be able to write and delete files, basically I want everyone to be able to add to this drive without a password or anything. I've read a lot of questions on here, but nothing works.

When I ran `ls -l` it says this-

```
testbox@hpubuntu:/media$ ls -l 
testbox total 4 drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Sep 3 03:59 hpmachine.
```

The end word "hpmachine" is highlighted in green.

Comment: You are showing testbox as user name. `testbox@hpubuntu`  you also can see that with: `echo $USER`  See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/324705/first-full-backup-on-usb-permission-denied/324942#324942

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't have logged in with `first`. A common configuration of Ubuntu sets it up so that you don't have to enter your username or password... Are you sure you actually entered something to log in at all?

As oldfred mentioned, you can use `echo $USER` to see your actual username, you can also use `whoami`.

There's never only one user on a Linux box or, really, on any operating system. There are a number of accounts set up just for operation of the computer. You can see all the accounts on the box by typing `cat /etc/passwd`. The user names are before the first colon.

As oldfred mentioned, your prompt shows that your username is `testbox` and your hostname is `hpubuntu`.

The green highlight means that it's a directory with the *execute* bit set, which only means that you can access files within that directory. The permissions on the long listing (`drwxrwxrwx`) give you the same information.

I don't think you can change the ownership of a mount point, as that is defined when it's mounted. There's no reason to change it, anyway. It has full permissions, so any user on the box can do anything within the drive.

Please use the formatting options on your next question... Or, at least press Enter a couple of times. It makes things much easier to read.

Comment: Ran echo $USER and it says "testbox". That's not what I want the user to be named. I want it to be "first". Also when you click on that gear icon upper right corner, it has "first" next to the little head symbol and a checkmark. I thought that IS the user?                                                    Anyway, that's another fix for later.                                                                      My problem is I want this secondary HD to automount on bootup, and I need it to be read and write from anyone, so that the other computers on the LAN can copy and delete files from it.

Comment: Ran echo $USER  "testbox". That's not what I want the user to be named. I want it to be "first". When you click on that gear icon upper right corner, it has "first" next to the little head symbol and a checkmark. I thought that IS the user?                                                    Anyway, that's another fix for later.                                                                             My problem is I want this secondary HD to automount on bootup, and I need it to be read and write from anyone, so that the other computers on the LAN can copy and delete files from it. No Work

Comment: @N.T. Well, your username is `testbox`. You must have entered "first" into the field intended for your full name. The configuration file for mounted drives and partitions is `/etc/fstab`. That's where you set permissions and ownership (and everything else) for a mount point. For example, here's the line in my `/etc/fstab` that I use to auto-mount the Windows partition on my dual-boot system: `UUID=2EE63C53E63C1E11 /mnt/windows ntfs defaults,uid=0,gid=0,umask=0000` You'll need to read `man fstab` and maybe `man mount`.