# Problem in saving files in harddrive

Tags: disk, disk-usage

[image]My ubuntu is installed in SSD, and I have a HDD also. whenever I want to download something from the internet and try to save that in the HDD, it is showing error message. Is there any option to resolve that?

Comment: If would depend upon the exact error message, of course. You should probably add that to your question.

Comment: make sure you have created a directory you can write to eg chmod 777 directory

Comment: Are you mounting partition with fstab? What format is partition on HDD? If Windows type format, you have to mount giving yourself permissions. If ext4, you have to give ownership & permissions to yourself. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions  & similar to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/324705/first-full-backup-on-usb-permission-denied/324942#324942

Comment: You can type `chown "$(whoami):$(whoami)" ~ -R && chmod ug+rw ~ -R` to give you ownership and permissions