Uninstalling ubuntu 24.04 from dual boot. Both OS are ubuntu 24.04
I was working on Ubuntu pro 24.04 LTS. I messed up with /etc/passwd and /etc/group file which then crashed the OS with dbus message service failed error. which made me unable to access root privileges for user. I dual booted the machine with another ubuntu pro 24.04 to access the files, however the files are locked with the user password form previous OS.
I am trying to find a way to uninstall the previous OS without loosing any file.
Please help if there is a solution.

Did you use a different user name & password for new install. I use same when installing a test install and have no issues. User should be 1000 or first user. You can change user & permissions. Example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/324705/first-full-backup-on-usb-permission-denied/324942#324942 But as in answer below, you must have good backups.

You have a few options here:

Boot from your installation USB drive, select advanced options, go
into recovery mode, mount your file systems and copy your data
off--perhaps to a different USB drive
Boot from your installation USB, reinstall the OS, but keep the
filesystem intact during install

